# Can the flag box be draggable in Discussions?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, design, flags, discussions-space

On a question, I can drag the flag box around. This is useful, especially for custom moderator flags when I need to reference something in the post.

Unfortunately, the flag box in Discussions isn't movable and is "stuck" in the center of the page.

Could that box be updated so I can drag it somewhere else on the page if I'd like?